# Flush Aurora page cache for testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-aurora

Aurora has a Survivable Page Cache which means cached DB pages stay cached in RAM after a restart.
How would I flush the cache for performance testing on a cold query?  What is the equivalent of `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` etc.?

Comment: I'm curious...  Why do you want 'cold'?  Normally 'warm' is preferred for timing production queries.

Comment: To compare worst-case times.  In my particular use case (analytics, ad hoc reporting) i expect cold queries to be common.

Comment: If you do one analytics query for the last month, then do another ad hoc query, the second one will (probably) find all the necessary data blocks and perhaps all the necessary index blocks in RAM.